# PHP traverse txt, once string is found, insert text

Tags: php, arrays

I have a file, test.txt, and I would like to traverse it.  once I hind the "here" string, I'd like to place 'test' in the following line.

```
            $lines = array();
            $match = 'here';
            foreach(file('test.txt') as $line)
            {
            if((string)$match == (string)$line)
            {

                    array_push($lines, 'this');;
            }
            array_push($lines, $line);
```

Unfortunately, the if statement never resolves as true, even though there is a 'here' in the txt file.

Thanks

Comment: Each `$line` has a new line at the end, while your `$match` does not.

Comment: So, let me get it this way, you have a file called `test.txt` and inside it, you have a word `here`, and all you want to do is open the file, and replace that word `here` with `this`?

Comment: Try `if($match == trim($line))`

Comment: thanks Hamza. Answer question so that I can give you credit.

Comment: Yes @HamZaDzCyberDeV I need to give you some credit too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>**Credits goes to [Vedran Šego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667018/) from his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625613/#comment23905582_16625613).**</sub>

The problem is that `$line` contains a new line, so to remove it we'll be using [trim()](http://php.net/trim)

**Edit:** This code may have several problems as stated below in the comments by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/) and it seems I misunderstood what you wanted to do (instead of "adding" I replaced the matched string)

```
foreach(file('test.txt') as $line){
   if($match === trim($line)){
      array_push($lines, 'this');
   }
   array_push($lines, trim($line));
}
```

Comment: This is a good practical solution, but there are several small details that need to be addressed properly.

Comment: 1) The code as written does not *insert* content, it replaces it.

Comment: 2) If the line has whitespace at the beginning or end, it will be disregarded. So a line that reads `    here` (spaces at the beginning) will trigger the replacement; it's not clear if this is intentional.

Comment: Worth noting `$lines[] = $line` will perform better than `array_push`.

Comment: 3) If `$match` is a numeric string such as `"007"` this code will trigger on all lines that *convert* to that number, such as `07`. To prevent this you need to use `===` for the comparison and perhaps also cast to string for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually care for specifically working on the text line-by-line, you can do also this very easily with a regular expression:

```
$text = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$text = preg_replace('/^(here)$/m', "\\1\ntest", $text);
```

This type of solution has several important points you need to be aware of:

- The regular expression needs to be used in multiline mode (`/m` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)).
- The matched text is placed inside parentheses so that we can refer to it inside the replacement string. This way you can easily use a more complicated expression to match the lines you want to append content after.
- If your input file does not have Unix-style line endings (in practice this means "if it was created by a Windows application) then you will have to modify the expression to account for the additional `\r` character before each `\n` newline. A regular expression that works for both Unix and Windows line endings is

  ```
  $text = preg_replace("/^(here)(\r?\n)/m", "\\1\\2test\\2", $text);
  ```

Comment: LOL and I was going to edit my answer to add this :D [demo](http://viper-7.com/ttZzPc)

Comment: Note that the second regex will fail when `here` is at the last line since there is no new line after it

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: That's true! I 'm not sure how to fix it in a platform-agnostic manner though...

Comment: I was thinking about it for a while, and came to an idea, what about using `PHP_EOL`: `$output = preg_replace("/^(here)(\r?\n|$)/m", "\\1".PHP_EOL."test".PHP_EOL, $text);` ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: The "problem" with that it changes the newlines to the current platform's definition. I think it's not possible to do this in a correct and platform-agnostic manner without resorting to `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 1):

Thought i'd throw in my solution:

```
$text = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$match = 'here';

foreach ($lines as $idx => $line) {
  if (trim($line) === $match) {
    array_splice($lines, $idx, 0, $line);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I would use `preg_split("\r\n?|\n", $text)`

Comment: Or `explode("\n", str_replace("\r", '', $text))` if you wanted to avoid the regex heh, but good call!